# How to properly install pygame module in windows? And make games

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have written codes but it's showing cannot import pygame module

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: Installers are here: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Download pygame from here: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
If you are not sure which version of python you are running, execute the following code in your shell:

```
import sysconfig
version = sysconfig.get_python_version()
print(version) #Python3
print version #Python2
```

Usually, Python3 will also accept the print command without brackets, so using sysconfig is the safest way. Sysconfig will also tell you which minor version you are using (such as 3.4.5)

Once you have download pygame, try`import pygame` in your shell. If this does not work, type `help('modules')`. This will now list all your modules. If pygame is not in there, check in which folder all other modules are saved and move the pygame module to that file path.

You can also use sysconfig to display all the file paths python is using:

```
import sysconfig
paths = sysconfig.get_paths()
print(paths) #For Python2, see print method above
```

I don't quite understand what you mean with "And make games", but the pygame website has a great documentary and some example codes to help you learn progamming with the pygame module.

Hope I could help,
Narusan